Unable to start dependent containers using docker compose
I have two python services i.e. first_service and second_service. Following is the docker compose file:
version: '3'

services:
  first_service:
    build: ./first_service
    container_name: first_service
    depends_on:
      second_service:
        condition: service_healthy
    restart: on-failure
    links: 
        - second_service

  second_service:
    build: ./second_service
    container_name: second_service
    volumes:
      - /home/user/settings/condition/second_service:/app/second_service
      - /home/user/settings:/app/settings
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "test -f /app/settings/archive.sh && grep -q 'saket' /app/settings/archive.sh || exit 1"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 10s
      start_period: 10s

When I run docker compose up -d, second_service goes in the state Up 34 seconds (unhealthy)  and first_service goes in the state Created. When the second_service becomes healthy after sometime i.e. Up 38 seconds (healthy), first_service is still in Created state.
I tried using depends_on with service_healthy option but it does not complete the motive. I want the first_service to be up and running as soon as second_service becomes healthy at any point of time. It should happen through docker compose file only.

Unrelated to your question, but you should not be using links in your compose file. It is deprecated, unnecessary, and fragile.

If I reproduce your example, it looks like docker compose exits:
$ docker compose up
[+] Running 3/2
 ✔ Network containers_default             Created                0.1s
 ✔ Container containers-second_service-1  Created                0.0s
 ✔ Container containers-first_service-1   Created                0.0s
Attaching to first_service-1, second_service-1
second_service-1  | darkhttpd/1.14, copyright (c) 2003-2022 Emil Mikulic.
dependency failed to start: container containers-second_service-1 is unhealthy

Because compose exits, it is no longer managing the containers, so even if second_service becomes healthy, there's nothing waiting around to start first_service. This is apparently expected behavior, although I find it susprising.
The solution is to increase your start_period so that second_service is healthy by the time start_period expires. E.g:
  second_service:
    build: ./second_service
    container_name: second_service
    volumes:
      - /home/user/settings/condition/second_service:/app/second_service
      - /home/user/settings:/app/settings
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "test -f /app/settings/archive.sh && grep -q 'saket' /app/settings/archive.sh || exit 1"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 10s
      start_period: 30s

